# Why i am unable to fetch data on server and getting error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, nodemailer

I am unable to send data on server as getting error 'Uncaught (in promise), I have updated my mail ID and password but it's getting error again and again.

```
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setButtonText("sending...");
    let response = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/contact", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: { "Content-Type": "Application/json" },
    body: JSON.stringify(formDetail),});
```

***server***

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const cors = require("cors");
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

// server used to send send emails
const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use("/", router);
app.listen(5000, () => console.log("Server Running"));
console.log(process.env.EMAIL_USER);
console.log(process.env.EMAIL_PASS);  

const contactEmail = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: "gmail",
  auth: {
    user: "********@gmail.com",
    pass: "",
  },
});
```